# Using underscore in directory names and loading packages

Tags: packages

Using an underscore with the SetDirectory command works fine.

```
SetDirectory["D:\\at_work\\mathematica\\programming_maeder"]
```

Now I can load a package using Get["ComplexMap`"] or Needs["ComplexMap"].

But if I set the directory to the directory above

```
SetDirectory["D:\\at_work\\mathematica"]
```

The Get or Needs commands fails.

```
Get["programming_maeder`ComplexMap`"]
```

Since it is within a string I would have thought the above statement would work. Is there a way to use the underscore here?

A workaround is to rename the directory programmingMaeder but I would prefer to use the underscore.

Comment: You can either rename the directory and use the backtick notation or keep the directory name and use the normal path syntax of your operating system, i.e. `Get["D:\\at_work\\mathematica\\programming_maeder\\ComplexMap.m"]`.  The idea behind the backtick notation is that users will be able to simply write the package context after `<<` to load the package.  This requires the context name to agree with the directory and file names.  Context names simply cannot contain underscores.

Comment: have you tried the `Get[name,Path->{}]` form?

Comment: The Get command with the complete path suggested by Szabolcs works fine. Also the form suggested by george2079 works. Thank you both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment given by Szabolcs works as an answer. He suggested using:

```
Get["D:\\at_work\\mathematica\\programming_maeder\\ComplexMap.m"]
```

He also made it clear that one is not allowed to use an underscore in a Context name.

The comment given by george2079 also works as an answer. He suggested using:

```
Get["ComplexMap`", 
 Path -> {"D:\\at_work\\mathematica\\programming_maeder"}]
```

or

```
Get["ComplexMap.m", 
 Path -> {"D:\\at_work\\mathematica\\programming_maeder"}]
```

I hope I am doing the correct thing by taking their comments and posting them as an answer.

Comment: that's appropriate. Go ahead and accept it after a while.